# What is the preferred pattern for this case in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Stylistically, I wasn't sure of the best way to handle this case in JavaScript.

We start with this to get a copy of the previous model if it's available. Then, I'm creating an impairmentDiagnosisModel based on the values if their available.

`this._previousModel = this.impairmentsCollection.get(this.model.get('id')) || '';`

Option 1:

```
this._impairmentDiagnosisModel = new ImpairmentDiagnosisModel({
    id: this.model.get('id'),
    cdx: (this._previousModel && this._previousModel.get('diagnosis').cdx) || _.first(this._diagnosisClass).id,
    nonKeyFactor: this._previousModel && this._previousModel.get('diagnosis').nonKeyFactor,
    impairmentValue: this._previousModel && this._previousModel.get('diagnosis').impairmentValue,
    side: this._previousModel && this._previousModel.get('diagnosis').side,
    digit: this._previousModel && this._previousModel.get('diagnosis').digit
});
```

Option 2:

```
if(this._previousModel) {
    this._impairmentDiagnosisModel = new ImpairmentDiagnosisModel({
        id: this.model.get('id'),
        cdx: this._previousModel.get('diagnosis').cdx,
        nonKeyFactor: this._previousModel.get('diagnosis').nonKeyFactor,
        impairmentValue: this._previousModel.get('diagnosis').impairmentValue,
        side: this._previousModel.get('diagnosis').side,
        digit: this._previousModel.get('diagnosis').digit
    });
}
else {
    this._impairmentDiagnosisModel = new ImpairmentDiagnosisModel({
        id: this.model.get('id'),
        cdx: _.first(this._diagnosisClass).id
    });
}
```

With Option #1, it litters the model with unnecessary empty attributes but that is immaterial here. If the server receives empty attributes, they are ignored.

With Option #2, it is more code and easier to read but seems inefficient.

What is the preferred method in this case?

Comment: Shouldn't your models be ignorant of eachother?

Comment: @Shmiddty It's used for populating the UI with previously saved data that is retrieved from local storage

Comment: Always favor readability first.

Comment: @Mathletics That's kind of my thought as well and why I asked the question. Plus, the model is polluted with empty attributes as well with Option #1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 3 : you could clone your `_previousModel.get('diagnosis')` object and then modify it to add customized properties.

For example,

```
var data = (this._previousModel) ? _.clone(this._previousModel.get('diagnosis')) : {};
data.id = this.model.get('id');
data.cdx = data.cdx || _.first(this._diagnosisClass).id;

this._impairmentDiagnosisModel = new ImpairmentDiagnosisModel(data);
```

Comment: Well, don't I feel stupid. Thanks for an obvious answer that is exactly right.

Comment: @Brandon Don't worry, it happens :)